# Objects in ViewBag

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-3

I have started using MVC 3 and I really like working with it. It's a much better experience than WebForms on so many levels.

However I have a question about the ViewBag (the new ViewData)
I am very careful to stick to sound modeling practices where I tend to put everything my view needs into ViewModels. However as far as the ViewBag goes, are there any concerns other than poor modeling practice that suggests that ViewBag should be uses sparingly? I don't use it much myself, but a team mate asked the question today, and I could only recommend to limit its use since it's a weakly typed model,hacked to be cool using dynamic (sudo typed)

Form what I can tell there shouldn't be any performance impact from using it though? 
Am I right? It's just another object that get's applied to the view server-side.
I am not counting any performance impact of using dynamic (if there is one that can be measured)

What are your views on disadvantages (or even advantages) of using the ViewBag?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For me, the big problem is that ViewBag isn't type-safe and can easily produce run-time errors if you aren't careful.

A view bag is really just a convenience to prevent simple cases where you would otherwise need a new viewmodel. I routinely use them, but only for very simple data.

Comment: Yes, I agree, it seems a lot like a good place to place afterthoughts that didn't come up when you made your view model, or didn't fit. I typically use it for simple things like an int or some other simple object.

Answer (score 0):

from my post at:
http://completedevelopment.blogspot.com/2011/12/stop-using-viewbag-in-most-places.html

```
Even the built in templates give us support for ViewBag. The scaffolding templates create ViewBag.SomeEnumerable to use for our pages.
Sure - its quick code and since it's auto-generated will likely work ok. The problem comes in from the fact that ViewBag is a dynamic object. There are no compile time type checks. If you misspell something you won't be notified from the compiler.

I've seen this used in such bad ways, I would love to see it's usage curbed and applications cleaned up. 

So in a controller:
ViewBag.SomeProperty = "10"
and in the view:
@ViewBag.Som3Pr0p3rty
We won't ever know of this error. It won't even generate a runtime error since the misspelled name just generated a null.


Use ViewModels and save yourself from these potential problems. Our templates set a page title in ViewBag as well.


There are several options in setting a page title. Since this is a well known property one could argue that using it just for Title is ok. I wouldn't argue this. There are other options.
1. Set it in a section in the layout and render it from the client.
2. Use ViewBag.Title
3. Use a filter (seems much too complicated for a title)
4. Use a Model.Title field.

Since by default we have a ViewBag.Title field created and our templates also get it by default, I'll yield that in this case, its ok.

What about select lists?
Rather than the default 

 ViewBag.CustomerId = new SelectList(db.Customers, "CustomerId", "FirstName", order.CustomerId);


Do something like
yourViewModel.Customers = customers; //a loaded collection

and in your view
@Html.DropDownListFor(x => x.CustomerId, new SelectList(Model.Customers, "CustomerId", "Name"))

Or if you prefer to set your ViewModel to contain the SelectList


yourViewModel.Customers = new SelectList(db.Customers, "CustomerId", "Name", order.CustomerId);

and now your view would be slightly cleaner as:
@Html.DropDownListFor(x => x.CustomerId, x.Customers)

See, that's not so difficult now is it? Enjoy!
```